# How to choose the default Google account for a Google service?

Tags: google-account

I have 3 Google accounts - a personal account, a work account, and an NGO account I rarely use.

When I open a Google service (like photos.google.com), it opens it using my work account, even though I have both private and work Inbox tabs open.

Is there a way to let a Google Service know what is my default account to be used with it?

Comment: If you use Google Chrome, you could always use different browser profiles. Each browser profile is linked to one Google Account, so when going to Google services, you will automatically be logged in with the correct account, if you use the correct browser window.

Comment: Always first open your default account, than you can open your other accounts by clicking add another account

Comment: @Charlie So, the first Google tab opened in Chrome sets the default?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal Each profile is associated with a different Chrome window?

Comment: Yes (but you can have more than one window for each profile). See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&ref_topic=3421437

Comment: @AdamMatan yes,

Comment: @Charlie would you please summer it as an answer?

Comment: @AdamMatan, Done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always, first open your default account, than you can open your other accounts by clicking add another account.

1. First open you account with credentials which you want to make default account for current browser.
2. Now, Click your profile photo or email address at the top-right corner of the page.
3. Click Add account from the drop-down menu.
4. Enter the username and password for another account you want to access, and click Sign in.

Now the first account you logged in is your default account.

Comment: @AdamMatan, Its done

Comment: The first account remains default throughout. Is there a way to have work account as default for Gmail & Drive but personal account as default for Google News/Maps/YouTube?